# Programming call function in js

Tags: javascript

To exercise in javascript I have decided to write call function myself(calling). But I can't understand why the following error takes place:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'calledfunct' of undefined
    at Function.calling .....**
Here is the code:

```
var alex={
    name:"alex",
    surname:"surname"
}
let nameyourself = function(){
    console.log(`${this.name} ${this.surname}`);
}


Function.prototype.calling=function(smth){
    smth.prototype.calledfunct=this;
    return smth.prototype.calledfunct();
}
nameyourself.calling(alex);
```

Comment: `alex.prototype` does not exist, it's just a plain object.

Comment: try smth.__proto__ ( two underscores )

Comment: It worked too, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `Function.prototype.calling`, the parameter `smth` refers to `alex`, and `alex` doesn't have an attribute called `prototype`. Therefore, you are unable to set the property `calledfunc` of the undefined  attribute `prototype`.

If you define a prototype attribute on `alex` this error should go away.

```
var alex={
    name:"alex",
    surname:"surname",
    prototype: {}
}
```

Comment: But I thought that objects have prototypes

Comment: @Alexey_js Objects do have a prototype. `Object.getPrototypeOf({}) // Object { ... }`